# Backbone.Marionette BoilerPlate - Managing Regions

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, boilerplate

I am developing an Backbone.Marionette with Boilerplate framework structure.
in App.js - I am setting up the layout of the page inside App.initLayout function, by
adding regions - regionNav, regionMain, regionFooter.
The views to be shown on different routes are handled in the Controller.js 
in controller I have app defined.
What I want is to just load the view for regionMain in controller for different links
but I get regions that I ve laid down in App.js as undefined.
Therefore to tackle this I add regions bye using App.addRegions method in the contoller
and add footer and navigation view to it for each route function call, this is not correct
it should only load the view in regionMain.
Please help in how I can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can find a starting point [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410059/suggested-bootstrap-boilerplate-sample-for-backbone-marionette-application/11598371#11598371)
its not perfect, but it will help you get started